# Show all documents in a farm using Search/Fast Search

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search, fast-search

I want to show all the documents in the farm and ofcourse I don't want to use powershell for that as this will impact performance. I want to use something using search index. I think we can do this using data view webpart but I am not sure how to achieve the document file type and document name of all the documents in the farm?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use FAST Search Center?

Comment: Do you want to iterate all indexed items and retrieve them? Or just documents?

Comment: I want just documents will all the extensions right now.I don't want it to look like search view . I just want 1 webpart zone page and display the document properties , I am not sure if this is possible but I may also want to use pie charts utilizing that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a keyword query using the Search Core Results Web Part and the Fixed Query properties.

You will need to specify a property, but I'm pretty sure I've done some simple queries like 'isDocument=true' or you can specify the file extension if desired.